# What is the relationship between Benjamin and Leibowitz?

Tags: a-canticle-for-leibowitz

In *Fiat Homo*, one of the monks of the Albertian Order of Leibowitz (Brother Fingo) finishes a hand-carved woodcarving of Leibowitz (who had not yet been deemed a saint).

The woodcarving was passed down from generation to generation, and winds up in the possession of Dom Zerchi, the abbot of the monastary over 1000 years later in the *Fiat Voluntas Tua* section.

There were repeated references in particular to the smile on the statue's face, and the implication that the smile was that of Benjamin, the seemingly immortal Jewish hermit.

Brother Francis, who is the first in the story to encounter Benjamin, remarks upon the similarity when he sees the smile start to emerge during the carving process:

> But as the work progressed, Francis could not escape the feeling that the face of the carving was smiling a vaguely familiar smile. He sketched it thus, and the feeling of familiarity increased. Still, he could not place the face, or recall who had smiled so wryly.

And then again upon completion:

> "I know him!" Francis gasped, staring at the merry-but-sad wrinkled eyes, the hint of a wry smile at the corners of the mouth - somehow almost too familiar.
>
> "You do? Who is it then?" wondered Fingo.
>
> "It's - well, I'm not sure. I think I know him. But-"
>
> Fingo laughed. "You're just recognizing your own sketches," he offered in explanation.
>
> Francis was not so certain. Still, he could not quite place the face.
>
> *Hmm-hnnn!* the wry smile seemed to say.

Later on, Zerchi also reflects upon the resemblence:

> The image was old, very old. Some earlier ruler of the abbey had sent it down to a basement storeroom to stand in dust and gloom while a dry-rot etched the wood, eating away the spring grain and leaving the summer grain so that the face seemed deeply lined. The saint wore a slightly satiric smile. Zerchi had rescued it from oblivion because of the smile.
>
> "Did you see that old beggar in the refectory last night?" he asked irrelevantly, still peering curiously at the statue's smile.
>
> "I didn't notice, Domne. Why?"
>
> "Never mind, I guess I'm just imagining it."

The implication is that the image Fingo carved is that of Benjamin, rather than Leibowitz, or possibly that Benjamin *is* Leibowitz (which was also somewhat implied during Francis' encounter with Benjamin, and speculated upon widely within the monastery afterwards).

Benjamin himself stated in the *Fiat Lux* section that Leibowitz was a "distant relative":

> "now, now, paulo. one of them once mistook me for a distant relative of mine - name of Leibowitz. He thought I had been sent to deliver him a message - or some of your other scalawags thought so. I don't want it to happen again, so I throw pebbles at them sometimes. Hah! I'll not be mistaken for that kinsman again, for he stopped being any kin of mine."
>
> The priest looked puzzled. "Mistook you for whom? Saint Leibowitz? Now, Benjamin! You're going too far."
>
> Benjamin repeated it in a mocking singsong: "Mistook me for a distant relative of mine - name of Leibowitz, so I throw pebbles at them."
>
> Dom Paulo looked thoroughly perplexed. "Saint Leibowitz has been dead a dozen centuries. How could-" He broke off and peered warily at the old hermit. "Now, Benjamin, let's don't start that tale wagging again. You haven't lived twelve cent-"

So what is the relationship between Leibowitz and Benjamin?  Is the woodcarving supposed to be of Leibowitz, or of Benjamin?  Are they supposed to be one and the same, despite Benjamin's claims?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fingo actually starts carving the statue *before* Francis meets the Wanderer:

> Fingo’s assignment to the kitchen was punitive and probably temporary. He was a woodcarver by trade, and normally worked in the carpenter’s shop. But some incident of self-assertion, in connection with a figure of the Blessed Leibowitz which he had been permitted to carve, had caused the abbot to order him transferred to the kitchen until he showed some signs of practicing humility.

We're never told exactly in what way Fingo had asserted himself; but it seems probable that it had to do specifically with the statue's smile.

> *Hmm-hnnn!* the wry smile seemed to say.
>
> The abbot found the smile irritating, however. While he allowed the work to be completed, he declared that be would never permit it to be used for the purpose originally planned—as an image to be placed in the church if the canonization of the Beatus were ever accomplished. Many years later, when the whole figure was completed, Arkos caused it to be set up in the corridor of the guesthouse, but later transferred it to his study after it had shocked a visitor from New Rome.

It appears, then, that although Fingo intended (and everyone takes) the statue to represent Leibowitz, somehow the smile is that of Benjamin. The implication, though, is not that Leibowitz and Benjamin are "one and the same"—as you point out, Benjamin states that Leibowitz is no longer a relative of his, presumably stopping when he converted to Catholicism. To the best of my knowledge, Walter Miller never discussed why he gave the statue the Wandering Jew's smile. I have a personal belief, but it's not particularly objectively true so I won't put it down here.

Comment: Can you share your belief in a comment? I'd like to hear it.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens Oh now you're going to make me try and remember it 10 months later :-D Give me a while, and I'll see if I can reconstruct it.

Answer (score 3):

The "distant relative" comment is trivial: Leibowitz is a Jewish name<sup>1</sup>, and Benjamin is a Jew. Despite the possibility of people converting to Judaism, there is a common conceit that all Jews are related.

Nor I suppose is it entirely unreasonable to think that Benjamin would come back to Abby centuries later, which would account for the familiarity of his face. It is merely the author's conceit that that happened at just the right time to be included in the story.

---

<sup>1</sup> A fact which also makes the title a bit intriguing because a canticle is an originally Catholic observance.

Comment: I figured the "distant relative" may have been a reference to styling all Jews as being part of the same "family", but I think you may have the sequence of events off for the second part of your answer: Francis meets Benjamin as a nameless hermit, then comes back to the abbey and Fingo, who has not met Benjamin, carves the wood piece. Benjamin then shows up several hundred years later, where he is now known by the residents of the monastary. 1000+ years after the wood was carved, yet another person comments on the similarity to Benjamin.